# Create multiple records related to existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails noob trying to develop a simple exercise log app, and I'm up against my limits. A user selects a category, and a specific workout, and I return a list of exercises belonging to that workout.

An effort is a user specific instance of an exercise.

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :efforts
end

class Effort < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
end
```

I'm retrieving the list of exercises in the efforts controller

```
class EffortsController < ApplicationController
  def log_workout
    @exercises = Exercise.where("category_id = ? AND workout_id = ?", params[:exercise][:category_id], params[:exercise][:workout_id])
    @effort = Effort.new
  end
end
```

My problem is that I'm not sure about my approach up to this stage. It does work so I have attempted to enable the user to log their workout by using a form like the following but I'm  (not surprisingly) not getting the right info back from it and I'm not sure where to go with it...

```
<%= form_tag save_workout_path, method: :put do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Exercise</th>
    <th>Sets</th>
    <th>Reps</th>
  </tr>
  <%= @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
  <%= fields_for "efforts[]", @effort do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= exercise.name %></td>
      <td><%= f.number_field :sets %></td>
      <td><%= f.number_field :reps %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Log it" %>
<% end %>
```

If anybody has any thoughts/guidance/solutions I'd appreciate it